# select some columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

I have two data frames with many columns, D1 (with columns: V1_1, V1_2....) and D2 (with columns: V2_1, V2_2...).
But I'm not interested in all the columns, I only want the columns that other third data frame indicates.
This third data frame has two columns, the first one is the name of a data frame, and the second one is a list with the name of some variables.
Something like that:

```
DataFrame | Vbles 
D1        | ['V1_1','V1_27','V1_30'] 
D2        | ['V2_2','V2_3']
```

Suposse that its name is var_sel and the index is 'DataFrame'.

Now I want to extract from D1 the variables from `var_sel[Vbles][var_sel.index=='D1']`, but I don't know how.
I have tried doing:

`col=var_sel[Vbles][var_sel.index=='D1']`

`col= col[D1]`

And I obtain:

```
"['V1_1','V1_27','V1_30']"
```

Now, I want that columns from D1, so I try:

`D1[col]` and `D1[[col]]` too.

But I get an Error... Could someone help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the code that creates the dataframe itself? The wording of your question is slightly confusing

Comment: I have done some correlation analysis in each dataframe (D1 and D2) with a sample of that, and then I have kept the result variables of that analysis in this dataframe called var_sel, where I indicate for each dataframe (D1 and D2) which are the variables with which I want to stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
col = var_sel.loc['D1', 'Vbles']
D1.loc[:, eval(col)]
```

The problem is that your lists `['V1_1','V1_27','V1_30']` are actually stored as strings`"['V1_1','V1_27','V1_30']"`. To be able to use them like lists, we have to turn them into a list. We can use `eval` for that.

`eval` basically takes python code to be executed, as a string and returns whatever the executed code returns. In our case this code is a list literal `['V1_1','V1_27','V1_30']` which returns a list.

It should be noted that eval can be dangerous to use because as you can imagine, it will execute anything you throw at it, so it can be a gigantic security issue. That being said, if you are using it to transform some lists that are in string form into list form in the privacy of your own machine, it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: _eval_ is a discouraged technique - there are better ways to extract column names, e.g. with RE

Comment: Glad it works! And agreed @volcano - I added a paragraph to the answer about the unsafeness of `eval`. That being said, given that the author themselves constructed the lists in the DataFrame, they can guarantee that they will just evaluate to harmless lists of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. But if you want the names of columns from DataFrame D1 (stored separate, then you could try:

D1.columns

If this is not what you seek, then giving a snippet of your code might help.

Comment: Follow up questions and requests for clarification/code belong in the comments section, not as answers. Until you have enough rep to comment, focus on answering questions that do not require more information or clarification.